# Force autocomplete form save on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, safari, auto-complete

While on some websites, iPad Safari automatically asks to save form data like Us/Pwd, on other pages, it never asks for the same.

How can we force it to ask for form data save on any website?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following bookmarklet to safari:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20ca,cea,cs,df,dfe,i,j,x,y;function%20n(i,what)%7Breturn%20i+%22%20%22+what+((i==1)?%22%22:%22s%22)%7Dca=cea=cs=0;df=document.forms;for(i=0;i%3Cdf.length;++i)%7Bx=df%5Bi%5D;dfe=x.elements;if(x.onsubmit)%7Bx.onsubmit=%22%22;++cs;%7Dif(x.attributes%5B%22autocomplete%22%5D)%7Bx.attributes%5B%22autocomplete%22%5D.value=%22on%22;++ca;%7Dfor(j=0;j%3Cdfe.length;++j)%7By=dfe%5Bj%5D;if(y.attributes%5B%22autocomplete%22%5D)%7By.attributes%5B%22autocomplete%22%5D.value=%22on%22;++cea;%7D%7D%7Dalert(%22Removed%20autocomplete=off%20from%20%22+n(ca,%22form%22)+%22%20and%20from%20%22+n(cea,%22form%20element%22)+%22,%20and%20removed%20onsubmit%20from%20%22+n(cs,%22form%22)+%22.%20After%20you%20type%20your%20password%20and%20submit%20the%20form,%20the%20browser%20will%20offer%20to%20remember%20your%20password.%22)%7D)();
```

You will need to know how to manipulate an existing bookmark to paste this small program in the place a bookmark normally has the URL. This is exactly how programs like [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/extras) and [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/add) and others use a bookmarklet (which is really a program stored as a bookmark) to change or act on the page you are currently browsing.

Since you should always be a little suspicious when someone posts a program for you to run - here is a clearer version that shows we just loop over all the elements and **blindly turn on autocomplete** for each.

This makes up for web developers that forgot or intentionally did not enable autocomplete.

---

Same script as above, but [nicely formatted](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and without the bookmarklet wrapper:

```
function () {
    var ca, cea, cs, df, dfe, i, j, x, y;

    function n(i, what) {
        return i " "
        what((i == 1) ? "" : "s")
    }
    ca = cea = cs = 0;
    df = document.forms;
    for (i = 0; i < df.length; i) {
        x = df[i];
        dfe = x.elements;
        if (x.onsubmit) {
            x.onsubmit = "";
            cs;
        }
        if (x.attributes["autocomplete"]) {
            x.attributes["autocomplete"].value = "on";
            ca;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < dfe.length; j) {
            y = dfe[j];
            if (y.attributes["autocomplete"]) {
                y.attributes["autocomplete"].value = "on";
                cea;
            }
        }
    }
    alert("Removed autocomplete=off from "
    n(ca, "form")" and from "
    n(cea, "form element")", and removed onsubmit from "
    n(cs, "form")". After you type your password and submit the form, the browser will offer to remember your password.")
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation concerning what the purpose of the bookmarklet is anyhow it works? This would help in reducing concerns of potential users to load a bookmarklet from a more or less anonymous source.

Comment: yes sure...i would also like to understand how to use this...